# Parse path length to <=260 characters correctly. Strange behaviour with 260-character Paths

Tags: python, windows

I'm making a function to parse a file path + name for Windows computers.

Here's my code:

```
def parse_out_path(directory, filename, extension):
    """Ensures filenames are valid. Strips disallowed characters and ensures path is not too long for Windows"""

    # Sanitize name to avoid illegal characters.
    filename = sanitize_filename(filename)
    total_len = len(os.path.join(directory, '{}.{}'.format(filename, extension)))
    if total_len > 260:
        # Shave excess characters from filename
        excess = total_len - 260
        filename = filename[:-excess]

    return os.path.join(directory, '{}.{}'.format(filename, extension))
```

This function generates the output file path with the filename and extension. If it is longer than the Windows limit (260 characters), it shaves some of the filename off to be compliant.

For example:

If `C:\long\path\here\example-file.txt` is 5 characters too long (265 characters), it becomes `C:\long\path\here\example.txt` (260 characters).

When I then run this with a filename that's too long, for example:

```
filename_too_long = '01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
parsed_path = ScraperUtils.parse_out_path(os.getcwd(), filename_too_long, 'txt')
open(parsed_path, 'w')
```

This *does* write successfully without any OSErrors. But when I open Windows File Explorer and click Properties, the Location field shows as:

`\\?\C:\Users\<rest of path>`

If I open the textfile in Notepad++ or WordPad, these programs either crash or fail to open the file.

If I change my code to create 259-character long filenames the strange symbols at the front of the path disappear. But the file still can't be opened in Notepad++.

If I change my code to create 258-character long filenames, everything appears to work as it should.

Can anyone explain why I'm seeing this strange behaviour? Is 260-characters actually the Windows path limit, or is it infact shorter?

Comment: The limit is 260 characters *including* the nul terminator, which leaves 259 characters for the path itself. This limit goes back to the DOS days, and it was only recently extended to 32K with the (optional, default off) [long paths support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) introduced in Windows 10 version 1607.

Comment: Your function also has to restrict the filename length, including the extension, to 255 characters, which is the maximum filename length of most filesystems, including NTFS and FAT32.

Comment: Python 3.6+ supports long normalized paths with up to about 32,760 characters if they're enabled at the system level. Each component name is still limited to 255 characters.

Comment: All versions of Windows and Python support long verbatim (extended) paths that begin with the "\\?\" prefix. A verbatim path has to be fully qualified; can only use backslash as the path separator; can't have any "." or ".." components; and vebatim UNC paths have to use the "UNC" device (e.g. "\\?\UNC\server\share"). With a verbatim path, you should also be sure to avoid reserved DOS device names (e.g. "nul", "nul : text", "nul  ...txt", and so on) and names that end with trailing dots and spaces (e.g. "spam. . . .") in the final component because it will let you create these abnormal names.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information Eryk Sun, I wasn't aware of this 255-character filename limitation and I've added this to my function. Additionally, thanks for explaining the \\?\ prefix!

Comment: There's another limit that's not discussed as much. When creating a directory, if long-path support isn't enabled and it's not a verbatim path, the system reserves 12 characters for an 8.3 short filename, plus 1 character for the trailing null, in which case the longest path you can pass to `os.mkdir` is 247 characters.

Comment: @ErykSun: It seems that all your comments combined together will present a good answer. Please consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this forum thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/256-character-limit-still-exists-on-windows-10/88c58c92-4835-474b-83c1-79277d55317a):

> ... Windows Explorer is still unable to open files stored in a folder whose path length exceeds 259 characters ...

The problem is your program allows a filepath to be 260 when the limit is 259 for windows file explorer. Changing `260` to `259` in your code should do the trick. As for other applications like notepad++, the limit might be less than that, I'm not really sure (if I were to guess it's probably 256).